# Need help on very simple if statement in function

Tags: javascript

I keep getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
Here is my code:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if numHours >= 8 {
        return "string 1";
    else {
        return "string 2";
    }
}
sleepCheck(10)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your assessment in parentheses:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "string 1";
    else {
        return "string 2";
    }
}
sleepCheck(10)
```

For single-statement `if`/`else` the omission of curly braces is legitimate:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if (numHours >= 8)
        return "string 1";
    else
        return "string 2";
}
sleepCheck(10)
```

As are the semi-colons (unfortunately); but the parentheses are obligatory.

Answer (score 2):

if condition has to be in parentesis

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "string 1";
    }else {
        return "string 2";
    }
}
sleepCheck(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it must have parenthesis to wrap the condition being checked in the if statement. Also you "should" be using semicolons after var declarations and statements such as your function call.

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "string 1";
  }else {
    return "string 2";
  }
};

sleepCheck(10);
```

Comment: Try writing practice code like this at jsbin.com. It will give you error warnings for missing semi-colons and parentheses. Also, lint your code with a tool such as jshint. JS Bin is really helpful for beginning to learn javascript.